# Different behaviour of bash script on supervisor start and restart

Tags: linux, bash, shell, supervisord

I have bash script which do something, (for example:)

```
[program:long_script]
command=/usr/local/bin/long.sh
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/long.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/long.out.log
```

and it is bounded to supervisor. 
I want to add if check in this script to determine is it executed by:

- supervisor> start long_script

or

- supervisor> restart long_script

I want something like that:

```
if [ executed by start command ]
then
    echo "start"
else
    echo "restart"
fi
```

but i don't know what should be in if clause. 
Is it possible to determine this? 
If not, how to achieve different behaviour of script for start and restart commands?
Please help.

Comment: Is the `supervisor>...`  command executed manually?

Comment: This highly depends on what start and restart do, and what they are (bash function, external program). If they are a progeam and spawn a new process, you should be able to find its parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the code there is no current difference between a restart and a stop/start. Restart within the supervisorctl calls:

```
self.do_stop(arg)
self.do_start(arg)
```

There is no status within the app for "restart" though there is some discussion of allowing different signals. The supervisor is already able to send different signals to the process. (allowing more control over reload/restart has been a [long standing "gap"](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/53))

This means you have at least two options but the key to making this work is that the process needs to record some state at **shutdown**

**Option 1.** The easiest option would be to use the `supervisorctl signal <singal> <process>` instead of calling `supervisorctl restart <process>` and record somewhere what signal was sent so that on startup you can read back the last signal.

**Option 2.** However a more interesting solution is to not expect any upstream changes ie continue to allow restart to be used and distinguish between stop, crash and restart

In this case, the only information that will be different between a start and a restart is that a restart *should* have a much shorter time between the shutdown of the old process and the start of the new process. So if, on shutdown, a timestamp is recorded, then on startup, the difference between now and the last shutdown will distinguish between a start and a restart

To do this, Ive got a definition like yours but with stopsignal defined:

```
[program:long_script]
command=/usr/local/bin/long.sh
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/long.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/long.out.log
stopsignal=SIGUSR1
```

By making the stop from supervisord a specific signal, you can tell the difference between a crash and a normal stop event, and not interfere with normal kill or interrupt signals

Then as the very first line in the bash script, i set a trap for this singal:

```
trap "mkdir -p /var/run/long/; date +%s > /var/run/long/last.stop; exit 0" SIGUSR1
```

This means the date as epoch will be recorded in the file /var/run/long/last.stop everytime we are sent a stop from supervisord

Then as the immediate next lines in the script, calculate the difference between the last stop and now

```
stopdiff=0
if [ -e /var/run/long/last.stop ]; then
    curtime=$(date +%s)
    stoptime=$(cat /var/run/long/last.stop | grep "[0-9]*")
    if [ -n "${stoptime}" ]; then
            stopdiff=$[ ${curtime} - ${stoptime} ]
    fi
else
    stopdiff=9999
fi
```

stopdiff will now contain the difference in seconds between the stop and start or 9999 if the stop file didnt exist.

This can then be used to decide what to do:

```
if [ ${stopdiff} -gt 2 ]; then
    echo "Start detected (${stopdiff} sec difference)"
elif [ ${stopdiff} -ge 0 ]; then
    echo "Restart detected (${stopdiff} sec difference)"
else
    echo "Error detected (${stopdiff} sec difference)"
fi
```

You'll have to make some choices about how long it actually takes to get from sending a stop to the script actually starting: here, ive allowed only 2 seconds and anything greater is considered a "start". If the shutdown of the script needs to happen in a specific way, you'll need a bit more complexity in the trap statement (rather than just `exit 0`

Since a crash shouldnt record any timestamp to the stop file, you should be able to tell that a startup is occurring because of a crash if you also regularly recorded somewhere a running timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem. But I don't know about supervisor. Please check whether this idea works.

Instantiate a global string variable and put values to the variable before you enter the supervisor commands. Here I am making your each start and restart commands as two bash programs.

program : supervisor_start.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting.."
supervisor> start long_script
supervisor_started_command="start" # This is the one
echo "Started.."
```

program : supervisor_restart.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "ReStarting.."
supervisor> restart long_script
supervisor_started_command="restart" # This is the one
echo "ReStarted.."
```

Now you can see what is in "supervisor_started_command" variable :)

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $supervisor_started_command == "start" ]
then
    echo "start"
elif [ $supervisor_started_command == "restart" ]
    echo "restart"
fi
```

Well, I don't know this idea works for you or not..